# intellij python global environment set fail

Tags: python, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I set some environment variables in /etc/profile or .bashrc ,all can not be use in intellij with python when runtime. 
so I have to set those variables in in intellij in here bellow.
[idea set global environment variables for all projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P47B9.png)

however, i run a script code like this :

```
import os
print os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] # intellij auto set ,work fine
print os.environ['CUDA_HOME']` # i set , failed, key_error.
```

the output surprised me. 
they both be set in the same place and same format. but behave different.

anyone can explain? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting environment variables in `.bashrc` make them relative to one user's session only.

And `/etc/profile` limit env variables to the shell.

Set your variables in : `/etc/environment` or `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`

See : http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html

Comment: thanks,man,,but can you explain the intellij behavior?  This is what I really want to adress.